# How to access a worksheet property using a variable?

Tags: vba, excel, enums, worksheet

**Situation:**

Whilst writing an answer for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271804/retaining-existing-excel-worksheet-protection-when-enabling-grouping) on SO I got stuck with the following:

**Question: How to pass a worksheet property as a variable?**

For example, I was looking at worksheet protection properties and wanted to assign them via a variable e.g. with psuedo code:

```
myVar =  ProtectDrawingObjects 

If Worksheets("Sheet1").myVar = True Then ......
```

**What I have tried:**

1) In the first instance I searched for a set of enums to use but to no avail. I found references in [Visual Basic](http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/windowsforms/xlsio/Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base~Syncfusion.XlsIO.ExcelSheetProtection.html) to enums but not the kind of thing I am after. I was looking for something like `Activesheet.Protection(1)`.

2) I then tried concatenation (which I expected to see fail) e.g.

```
If ws & "." & "ProtectDrawingObjects" = False Then MsgBox "False"
```

Which indeed failed with

> Object doesn't support this property or method

3) I tried declaring object/variant variables and assigning values to these resulting in expected Type Mismatch errors or the above property not supported error.

4) I also tried to find similar SO questions such as: [Get worksheet property using worksheet variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799875/get-worksheet-property-using-worksheet-variable), but that seemed to imply I would need to create a custom property rather than the access the existing property of the worksheet.

5) As per @TimWilliam's helpful suggestion I tried the [`CallByName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function) function e.g.

```
Dim result As Boolean
result = CallByName(ws, "ProtectDrawingObjects", VbGet)
```

This worked well for those properties that commenced with "Protect" e.g.  `"ProtectDrawingObjects`" but not for any of the properties that commenced with 
"Allow" e.g. `"AllowFormattingCells"`; which returned:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

All the properties are `READ` and there clearly is a `Get` mechanism as one can do:

```
If ws.Protection.AllowFormattingCells = False then
```

***Is it simply not exposed via `CallByName()` ? And is there a workaround?***

**Overall objective:**

I wanted to have the different possible properties of the protection object in an array e.g. ("AllowDeletingColumns", "AllowDeletingRows",......) and then loop to test whether they were set to `True` or `False`.

I know I can use `If` statements to determine the states but I am interested in if there is a way essentially to do the following?

```
Worksheet.myVar
```

Where in pseudo code, in a loop, this would be

```
If Worksheet.myArr(i) = False Then ..Do Something.....
```

Comment: You can likely use `CallByName()` for this.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function

Comment: How can i set the value in a similar fashion? ws.myVar = False..... I assume using the vbLet but am unsure how to assign to the worksheet protection.

Comment: Yes, use the vbLet/vbSet options.  Eg:   `CallByName ws, "ProtectDrawingObjects", VbLet, True`

Comment: This allows me to access the value but is it technically not possible to do worksheet.myVar?

Comment: Also, CallByName(ws, "AllowFormattingCells", VbGet) fails with object does not support this property or method. It is read only so I would have expected to be able to get its value.

Comment: Edited comment from earlier: I used result = CallByName(ws, "ProtectDrawingObjects", VbGet) and it worked.

Comment: I have noticed that all the properties that start with "Protect" can be accessed with vbGet, but all those starting with "Allow" cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too large for a comment, but you can use CallByName on worksheet protection "Allowxxxxxx" properties.  Note these are properties of `Worksheet.Protection`, not direct properties of `Worksheet`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1
Debug.Print CallByName(ws.Protection, "AllowFormattingCells", VbGet) '>> False
```

or

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim p As Object

Set ws = Sheet1

Set p = CallByName(ws, "Protection", VbGet)
Debug.Print CallByName(p, "AllowDeletingColumns", VbGet) '>> False
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I’m still interested in if I can do ws.myVar =. ......... is this possible? Or have I missed something here and am being dumb?

Comment: No there's no facility in VBA for that kind of dynamic evaluation: the only thing you could maybe do is use VBE programming to construct a dynamic procedure and execute that.  E.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant/10037332#10037332

Comment: Great. I will have a look at that. I neglected to mention that I had started to look at the VBIDE to see if I could do anything there but stalled.